# Tortoise SVN Client and getting repo-browser url from .svn folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-client

I have this file structured svn directory and file:
[image]

When I try to see repo browser:

[image]

Tortoise can easly find the url of this folder:
[image]

I wonder that how tortoise got the url of the folder where I clicked to see in Repo Browser?

**Edit:**

```
Tortoise SVN 1.8+
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just ran `c:\DirectoryOfMyProjectWhicHasHiddenSvnFolder>svn info`
Result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In .SVN folder `ws.db` file which contain all the information, It's in Sqlite format.

You can open it using any SQLite tool. I have used Sqlite firefox plugin.

Goto table `Repository` and read 'ROOT'.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That information is stored in your working copy in `.svn` folder (for SVN 1.6 there is `.svn` folder in every folder of your working copy; for SVN 1.7 it's only at the top level).

Comment: Yes you are right. But I wonder that can I get this directory's repository folder?

Comment: You are not supposed to access it directly - only via SVN commands. Otherwise you can corrupt it and then you are toast :)